# KIF Tapping Disabled Button

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa, ui-testing, kif

I am using KIF to test my UI. I have a (very basic) login screen and the button on the screen only becomes enabled after text has been entered into both the email and password field. I want to write a KIF test using `[tester]` to test whether or not that button can be tapped. Is that possible?

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
if([tester waitForViewWithAccessibilityLabel:@"loginButton"].isProbablyTappable){

        // button tappable
    }
```